# jsrender is not working inside ajax call

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I am using jsrender to bind table.

My Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Script/jsrender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="../demos.html">JsRender Demos</a><br />

<h3>Using {{if}} and {{else}} to render conditional sections.</h3>

 <script id="movieTemplate" type="text/html">
<tr>
    <td>{{>content_id}}</td>
    <td>{{>Title}}</td>
    <td>{{>content_type}}</td>
    <td>{{>CreatedOn}}</td>
</tr>
</script>

<table>
<thead><tr><th>id</th><th>title</th><th>type</th><th>createdon</th></tr></thead>
<tbody id="movieList"></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Default.aspx/retieve_content_details",
    data: "{ 'n_module_id' :1, 'n_number_of_records' :10}",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#movieList").html(
            $("#movieTemplate").render(data.d)
        );
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Data coming from server side is

```
[{ "content_id": 1, "Title": "Testing", "content_type": "Hyperlink", "rich_text": null, "URL": "http://www.google.co.in", "CreatedBy": "Wayne", "CreatedOn": "\/Date(1390947274213)\/" }, { "content_id": 2, "Title": "Testing Rich Text", "content_type": "Rich Text", "rich_text": "I think Intranet Content Management is also working fine.\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cbr /\u003ePlease test at staging. Locally its working fine.\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cbr /\u003eThanks \u003cbr /\u003eBhagirathi", "URL": null, "CreatedBy": "Wayne", "CreatedOn": "\/Date(1390947346907)\/" }];
```

when i write dara.d inside the render its not working any data, but if copy the data and paste on a object and use that object then data is populating in the table.

Like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Default.aspx/retieve_content_details",
    data: "{ 'n_module_id' :1, 'n_number_of_records' :10}",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        var test_data = [{ "content_id": 1, "Title": "Testing", "content_type": "Hyperlink", "rich_text": null, "URL": "http://www.google.co.in", "CreatedBy": "Wayne", "CreatedOn": "\/Date(1390947274213)\/" }, { "content_id": 2, "Title": "Testing Rich Text", "content_type": "Rich Text", "rich_text": "I think Intranet Content Management is also working fine.\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cbr /\u003ePlease test at staging. Locally its working fine.\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cbr /\u003eThanks \u003cbr /\u003eBhagirathi", "URL": null, "CreatedBy": "Wayne", "CreatedOn": "\/Date(1390947346907)\/" }];
        $("#movieList").html(
            $("#movieTemplate").render(test_data)
        );
    }
});
```

Above code is working.

please help me

I searched in Google and found some good solutions, but those are not working for my case.

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any error when you call `.render` from ajax module ?

Comment: @dreamweiver: No. Its just showing empty tr.

Comment: Hey dont you think your ajax call should be within `$(document).ready(function() {  //ajax call here });`

Comment: obviously yes if your trying to  make a ajax call on load else it should be within a function which you may want to trigger at any time.as a matter of fact, i dont think its even making a ajax call now in your code. **REF:http://api.jquery.com/ready/**